# Raspberry Pi - ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero - adafruit pca9685

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c, adafruit

I'm struggling with my Raspberry. The Terminal prints out that there's a float division by zero but I don't divide anything in the code.
I already reseted the entire Pi and reinstalled everything. The first run after the reset was successful but afterwards every run shows up the error below.

Would be awesome if you could help me!
Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "robot2.py", line 43, in <module>
    kit.servo[servo1].angle = length1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_servokit.py", line 150, in __getitem__
    servo = adafruit_motor.servo.Servo(self.kit._pca.channels[servo_channel])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_motor/servo.py", line 103, in __init__
    super().__init__(pwm_out, min_pulse=min_pulse, max_pulse=max_pulse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_motor/servo.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.set_pulse_width_range(min_pulse, max_pulse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_motor/servo.py", line 49, in set_pulse_width_range
    self._min_duty = int((min_pulse * self._pwm_out.frequency) / 1000000 * 0xffff)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_pca9685.py", line 71, in frequency
    return self._pca.frequency
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_pca9685.py", line 145, in frequency
    return self.reference_clock_speed / 4096 / self.prescale_reg
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "robot2.py", line 43, in <module>
    kit.servo[servo1].angle = length1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_servokit.py", line 150, in __getitem__
    servo = adafruit_motor.servo.Servo(self.kit._pca.channels[servo_channel])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_motor/servo.py", line 103, in __init__
    super().__init__(pwm_out, min_pulse=min_pulse, max_pulse=max_pulse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_motor/servo.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.set_pulse_width_range(min_pulse, max_pulse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_motor/servo.py", line 49, in set_pulse_width_range
    self._min_duty = int((min_pulse * self._pwm_out.frequency) / 1000000 * 0xffff)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_pca9685.py", line 71, in frequency
    return self._pca.frequency
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_pca9685.py", line 145, in frequency
    return self.reference_clock_speed / 4096 / self.prescale_reg
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "robot2.py", line 43, in <module>
    kit.servo[servo1].angle = length1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_servokit.py", line 150, in __getitem__
    servo = adafruit_motor.servo.Servo(self.kit._pca.channels[servo_channel])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_motor/servo.py", line 103, in __init__
    super().__init__(pwm_out, min_pulse=min_pulse, max_pulse=max_pulse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_motor/servo.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.set_pulse_width_range(min_pulse, max_pulse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_motor/servo.py", line 49, in set_pulse_width_range
    self._min_duty = int((min_pulse * self._pwm_out.frequency) / 1000000 * 0xffff)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_pca9685.py", line 71, in frequency
    return self._pca.frequency
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_pca9685.py", line 145, in frequency
    return self.reference_clock_speed / 4096 / self.prescale_reg
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "robot2.py", line 43, in <module>
    kit.servo[servo1].angle = length1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_servokit.py", line 150, in __getitem__
    servo = adafruit_motor.servo.Servo(self.kit._pca.channels[servo_channel])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_motor/servo.py", line 103, in __init__
    super().__init__(pwm_out, min_pulse=min_pulse, max_pulse=max_pulse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_motor/servo.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.set_pulse_width_range(min_pulse, max_pulse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_motor/servo.py", line 49, in set_pulse_width_range
    self._min_duty = int((min_pulse * self._pwm_out.frequency) / 1000000 * 0xffff)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_pca9685.py", line 71, in frequency
    return self._pca.frequency
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adafruit_pca9685.py", line 145, in frequency
    return self.reference_clock_speed / 4096 / self.prescale_reg
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: It is possible that `self.prescale_reg` in `adafruit_pca9685.py` must be zero. Is that a file you wrote yourself?

Comment: ```self._min_duty = int((min_pulse * self._pwm_out.frequency) / 1000000 * 0xffff``` looks suspicious.  ```1000000 * 0xffff``` may be overflowing your variable size and returning 0.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your response! I'm using the current Adafruit Library. It's absolutely suspicious because now even the simplest sample code from this Library isn't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Brian, how can I fix it=

Comment: @Brian, in Python?! Or you meant that the result of the multiplication is bigger than nominator?

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the error is from the library code and hasn't been caught with `try` to turn it into a [friendly error message](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_PCA9685/issues/29). You can only tell by inspecting the implementation of another library but the offending value in `self.prescale_reg` is actually a value read from the controller device over the i2c bus.

There's a similar case of this mentioned on [Adafruit Forums: RaspberryPi Stepper HAT - example code not working](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=162250) which was diagnosed as a conflict between two progams using GPIO running.

I would double-check the physical i2c connectivity to the controller device, make sure it responds when you scan the i2c bus with `i2cdetect` (example in [Adafruit Learn: Adafruit 16 Channel Servo Driver with Raspberry Pi: Configuring Your Pi for I2C](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-servo-driver-with-raspberry-pi/configuring-your-pi-for-i2c)) and ensure you do not have any other conflicting use of GPIO pins for i2c in your code.